# X axis dates in wrong order

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

Plotting % bloom over time and across several sites. Plot looks correct but the x-axis dates aren't in chronological order.

Code:

```
Blue_bloom$site <- factor(bluecrop$site, levels = c("W. Ottawa", "E. Ottawa", "W. Van Buren", "E. Van Buren"))
BC_bloom2 <- ggplot(Blue_bloom, aes(x= date, y=as.numeric(value)))+ geom_point(aes(color = site))
BC_bloom2 + theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("skyblue", "steelblue", "deepskyblue2", "skyblue3")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group=1), method = "loess", se=T)+
  ylim(0,100)+
  labs(x = "date", y = "% bloom", title = "Bluecrop")`
```

Output:

[image]

Axis lists from left to right 6/11 and 6/12 before 6/3,6/5, and 6/8. Seems to be reading the first "1" in 11 and 12 as chronological...Tips??

Comment: Convert the dates to actual dates. At the moment they are strings or factors

Comment: convert date to dates (eg with as.Date(date)) instead of strings or factors and then use scale_x_date(date_format='%m/%d') to format them